# What are the accessibility impacts of react-virtualized?

Tags: react-virtualized

I'm wondering how react-virtualized handles accessibility. It seems like it might be difficult for a user to navigate to a particular section of the list using accessibility tools. Is react-virtualized a realistic option for projects that need to support accessibility?

Comment: This is a bit of a vague question. RV adds aria-* roles and sets tabIndex to assist with keyboard-based navigation. Components like `ArrowKeyStepper` also exist to help with navigating virtualized lists. But you're right, in general, windowing does introduce accessibility challenges.

Comment: Would it be different than any other scrolling element?

Comment: A bit late. Since the content outside of the viewport isn't created in the DOM it will not be visible to a user using a screenreader or similar tools. And since most screenreader tools use custom keybindings which override almost everything, its really hard to create any useful keybinding for them (the exception being using good semantic markup, which most tools understand).

Comment: @Mbrevda yes because the scrolled content is not present in the dom in a virtualized scroller.